# How can I track uploaded file names through my network using squid?

Tags: squid

I want to track the uploaded file names from my network using squid. For my network I want to monitor the uploads happening and also I want to generate a report of files that were uploaded from my network.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're talking about watching the files uploaded by users on your LAN to remote web sites. If that's not accurate, comment and I'll edit appropriately.

There's no general way to do what you're trying to by monitoring HTTP (or other) traffic leaving your LAN for the Internet. The local filenames of files being uploaded to remote servers don't have to cross the wire (and, indeed, don't with most typical file transfer protocols). The *content* of the files crosses the wire (obviously), so you could do something to try and monitor traffic for interesting content.

Even if you could monitor filenames, your users could always change the filenames before uploading them anyway.

Comment: thnx for pointing this out.